# Upload image in php

Tags: php, html, image

I want to add image in directory. The directory makes dynamically. But there is an error while uploading the image in directory and image can't upload due to this error the error is given below:

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 21

My code is here:

```
 <body>
            <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" />
            <input type="submit" name="pic" />
            </form>

    </body>
    </html>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['pic'])){
            $comimages = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
            $targetpath = mkdir("pageimage/pageid");
                $compath = $targetpath."/".$_FILES['filename']['name'];

                $comFileType=$_FILES['filename']['type'];
                $comFileSize=$_FILES['filename']['size'];
                $comFileSize=$comFileSize/1024;

                if($comFileSize<1000)
                {
                    $arrFileType=array("image/jpeg","image/png","image/gif","image/bmp");

                    if(in_array($comFileType,$arrFileType))

                    {

                        move_uploaded_file($comimages,$compath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo("invalid file format");    
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo("File Size Error");    
                }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Try to use the is_dir("pageimage/pageid") before creating the directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clue is in the error. The directory you are trying to create with `$targetpath = mkdir("pageimage/pageid");` already exists... so you can't make it again!

I would suggest doing a quick file exists check before trying to make it. There is a function for that: **[file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)**

Also, `mkdir()` returns a boolean (success or fail); not a file directory, so you won't be able to use your `$targetpath` variable as you expect.

Try this instead...

```
$targetpath = "pageimage/pageid";
if (!file_exists($targetpath)) {
    mkdir($targetpath);
}
...
```

Comment: I am not here to write your code for you, you should be able to figure out how to implement the examples I have given yourself. :)

Comment: file_exists says nothing about if this target really is a directory, it could be a file too.

Comment: I think the fact that the file could exist and be a file rather than a directory or not be writeable are additional checks that need to be done and are outside of the scope of the original question. If you do `is_dir()` and it returns false and you try `mkdir()`, it's going to fail as there already exists a file/folder with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the

```
$targetpath = mkdir("pageimage/pageid");
```

With:

```
$targetpath = "pageimage/pageid";
if(!is_dir($targetpath)){
mkdir($targetpath);
}
```

This way you are creating the directory only if it doesn't exist. It's normal the error you get as the directory already existed.

Answer (score 0):

You cant create a directory twice, befor creating the directory check for its existence.

you can use `is_dir()` and `is_writeable()` to be sure you can write to this directory.

see:
http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

http://uk.php.net/is_dir

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$targetpath = mkdir("pageimage/pageid");
```

With..

```
$targetpath = if(is_dir("pageimage/pageid")) ? "pageimage/pageid" : mkdir("pageimage/pageid");
```

You should check to see whether the folder exists before creating it.

Answer (score 0):

First question : Where is line 21? 
Anyway, you have to test if directory exists before creating it. Obviously, it seems to exist already in your case (folders are technically considered files here, see for example `is_dir()`). Use `file_exists()`.
Also beware that if you create a structure (a folder and a folder inside), you have to use the `$recursive` parameter, see PHP doc : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mkdir.php