# I'm upload image in subdirectory (images/my/) code in php

Tags: php

I'm upload image in subdirectory `images/my/` code in php
can anyone help......

this code i try.

```
$file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'];
move_uploaded_file("images/my/".$file_name);
```

Comment: Please take a look http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload image in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527357/upload-image-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `temp_name` instead of name to upload

```
$file_name = $_FILES["files"]["name"];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], "images/my/".$file_name);
```

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php! Where is the destination path??

Comment: `move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )` destination path is missing!!

Comment: Ohhh yes. Thanks for your corrections. i will modify it.

Answer (score 0):

**It's a simple way Which I used
 Use basename() function to get the file name,Use move_uploaded_file() function to move the uploaded file in specified directory**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader2.php" method="POST">
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$target_path = "uploads/";   // target directory
$target_path = $target_path.basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$target_path))
{
    echo "The file ".basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
}
else
{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
}
?>
```